# How can I sync signature & added dictionary words?

Tags: sync, microsoft-outlook-2010

I'm using MS Outlook on two PCs and see that the signature & customized spelling dictionary from one PC is not synced with the other. Is it possible and if yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to actually sync them rather than copy them over, you can do this with [**Windows Live Mesh**](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-mesh), which can sync your Office settings (styles, templates, custom dictionaries, signatures) between all your computers.

You need a [Live ID](http://www.passport.net/), which you will already have if you have a Hotmail address.  You can also make a Live ID using any other email address.

You can also use Mesh to sync IE favourites and any folders between your computers and optionally have them backed up online, where you can access them from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

the dictionary file is stored in the following location. If you have Windows-7 it should be in someplace similar to these paths.

> Windows XP Location:
>   C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\Microsoft\UProof\CUSTOM.DIC
>
> Windows Vista Location:
>   C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UProof\CUSTOM.DIC

the signature files are found here. Depending on formatting of your signature there may be multiple files and a folder for each one.

> Windows XP Location:
>   C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\Microsoft\Signatures

Comment: the multiple files and folders are used if you have a richtext or HTML signature.

Answer (score 0):

also, there are several files that might be handy as well.  Your .NK2 files hold your contacts that "auto fill" when you start to type their name.  Also, the .srs files are used by the signatures as well.

they are located at (on windows 7)

```
c:\users\<username>\appdata\roaming\microsoft\outlook
```